# Why is Django's authenticate taking too long to resolve?

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework

I have a Django project that uses [Django Rest Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/) and its `@list_route` among others to make api calls from my front-end.

The very first api call I make is:

```
website.com/api/staffs/authenticate
```

The endpoint code that catches that is:

```
@list_route(permission_classes=(AllowAny,))
def authenticate(self, request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if is_staff_or_admin(request.user):
            return Response(StaffSerializer(request.user).data)
    data = {'detail': AuthenticationFailed.default_detail}
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED, data=data)
```

That block of code takes a whopping 30-42 seconds to resolve! Any idea what might be causing this slowdown?

Comment: Why is this route a list_route

Comment: If you are authenticating one user shouldn’t you use @detail_route

Comment: I'm getting the data from session and I don't know their info in advance hence a list_route

Comment: Have you tried putting break points to see where the slowdown is happening?

Comment: your function seems ok, you need to add some break points or simple print to find the issue (maybe it's within your serializer)